# Magento: add customer company and telephone to "New account" transactional E-mail

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add customer company and telephone to "New account" transactional E-mail.

But it doesn't work.

I have tried like this :

```
Company :       {{var billing.company}} <br />
Telephone:      {{var customer.getTelephone()}} <br />
```

And also like that :

```
Company :       {{var customer.company}} <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no billing object in transactional emails... there are store, order and customer objects... you can add your own object but you would need your own filter as well.

For customer telephone I think {{var customer.telephone}} should work.

however the following link only tells us that not all the data are available on the available objects.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_email_template/index

You can also try calling the transactional email model from your controller to send emails:

```
$vars['your_attribute'] = 'attribute_value or object';


Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>$store_id))
      ->sendTransactional($template_id, $sender, $receiver_email, $receiver_name, $vars, $store_id);
```

and in you transactional email template just do {{var your_attribute}}.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm checking that now... {{var customer.telephone}} don't works for the telephone

Comment: try this solution: http://magentophp.blogspot.com/2011/08/passing-paramters-to-magento-cms-static.html ... this is for cms blocks but should work the same for email templates.